# Comparing two times in VBA

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

I want to see if the "time" part of a date/time is between midnight and 6:00 AM.

```
If Range("J" & RowCount) > #12:00:01 AM# And Range("J" & RowCount) < #6:00:00 AM# Then
```

What am I doing wrong? Range("J" & RowCount) is formatted as "General" and looks like this:

```
1/27/2015 2:00:00.000000 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

I put a date/time in cell A1 and used the following code.

```
Sub test()
    If Hour(Range("A1")) >= 0 And Hour(Range("A1")) < 6 Then
        Debug.Print "yeah"
    Else
        Debug.Print "nope"
    End If
End Sub
```

Instead of checking the entire date/time (which in Excel equals 42,031.08333) it uses the built-in `HOUR` function to to just look at the hour.

Adapted to your line of code:

```
If Hour(Range("J" & RowCount)) >= 0 And Hour(Range("J" & RowCount)) < 6 Then
```

Comment: Simple and works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a time is between midnight and 6:00AM you can just use the following code

```
If Hour(Range("A1")) < 6 Then
MsgBox "Time is between midnight and 6:00AM"
End If
```

You don't have to check if it is after midnight because the hours are recorded 1-24. You can also place this formula directly into the excel sheet if you are checking an entire column.

If you want to compare two specific times inclusive of each other this will do the trick. (note you can do this in Excel without VBA with a few changes)

```
Dim min As Date, max As Date, test As Date
min = TimeValue("12:00:01 AM")
max = TimeValue("6:00:02 AM")
test = TimeValue("1/27/2015 2:00:00 AM") 'replace with your range
test = test - Fix(test) 'this will remove the date portion of the time

If test >= min And test <= max Then
MsgBox test & " is between(inclusive) " & min & " and " & max
Else
MsgBox test & " is NOT between(inclusive) " & min & " and " & max
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Guitarthrower and CodeCamper. What if I need to find within the ranges of 12:00:01 and 6:00:02?

Comment: @KarlDrews if you take my code as is you will not get a type mismatch error (I tested it) what are you adding to the code that is causing this error?

Comment: I wasn't adding to the code. I think it had to do with cell contents I was comparing. I changed the cell contents to a decimal and it worked with this code: `If Range("J" & Rowstep) > TimeValue("00:00:01") And Range("J" & Rowstep) < TimeValue("06:00:02") Then`

Comment: @KarlDrews I updated my answer above to include an example of how you can compare two specific times inclusively. Is that what you are looking for?